# Two nodes with common base class declaring a namespaced service path

Tags: ros, rosservice, namespaces

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to be able to use a base class for declaring a service that separate nodes can utilize.  I thought I might be able to remap this in a launch file, but I must be doing something wrong.

To illustrate, imagine this class hierarchy:

```
class Base(object):
   def __init__(self):
      service = rospy.Service('get_state', ...) 

class Node1(Base):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Node1, self).__init__()
      rospy.init_node('node1')

class Node2(Base):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Node2, self).__init__()
      rospy.init_node('node2')
```

My hope would be that I could call:

```
$ rosservice my_pkg /node1/get_state
$ rosservice my_pkg /node2/get_state
```

Instead I have a service named "/get_state" and a collision.

I have tried a few things:

1. re-order so init_node is called before super of the base class
2. use ~get_state but this results in '/unnamed/get_state' which is still a collision
3. Use a launch file to remap the namespace

This last attempt included a launch file like this:

```
<node pkg="my_pkg" name="node1" type="node1">
   <remap from="get_state" to="node1/get_state"/>
</node>
```

The result still seems to be a name collision and only a /get_state for the first node and not the second.

Is there a simpler/better way to go about something like this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208126/two-nodes-with-common-base-class-declaring-a-namespaced-service-path/) by [j12y](https://answers.ros.org/users/21634/j12y/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is simply to include a tilde (~) when creating the service.  A good practice would be to call init_node from the main block to prevent the mistake of including more than one node in a single process.  There isn't much benefit in calling the init_node from within the class **init**.

```
# src/foo.py
class Base(object):
   def __init__(self):
      service = rospy.Service('set_state', ...)    # results in /set_state
      service = rospy.Service('~get_state', ...)   # results in /node1/get_state (as desired)

# nodes/node1.py
import foo
class Node1(foo.Base):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Node1, self).__init__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('node1')  # moved out of Node1.__init__
    node = Node1()
    ...
```

That seems consistent with the docs to keep the Service private to the node's namespace...
http://wiki.ros.org/Names

---

Originally posted by [j12y](https://answers.ros.org/users/21634/j12y/) with karma: 51 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-04-28**:
**rospy.init_node() is global; you should not call it more than once in your program.**

**Comment by [j12y](https://answers.ros.org/users/21634/j12y/) on 2015-04-28**:
Sure, but to be clear that is not the point of my question.  For illustration and brevity I omitted that Node1 and Node2 are two separate nodes / processes / sub-components -- not a single program.  That's why having a library with some common functionality seems valuable for consistency between.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-04-30**:
For clarity and to avoid calling rospy.init_node more than once, I usually call it from main().

**Comment by [j12y](https://answers.ros.org/users/21634/j12y/) on 2015-04-30**:
That's a great point, there probably is no need to have the init_node call in the **init** at all.  I guess I've gotten into the habit of keeping the main block simple in other projects.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rospy.init_node()` is global; you should not call it more than once in your program.

Instead, you could pass your node's namespace into the superclass constructor:

```
class Base(object):
   def __init__(self, name=""):
      service_name = 'get_state'
      if name:
         service_name = name + '/' + service_name
      service = rospy.Service(service_name, ...) 

class Node1(Base):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Node1, self).__init__('node1')
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1